# can't login as a newly added user in AWS lightsail instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, ssh, webserver, amazon-lightsail

I created an AWS lightsail instance with ubuntu. Additionally, in it's networking tab i create a TCP custom rule with 2200. After login i create a new user and verified its presence with the finger command. I edited /etc/ssh/ssh_config to have port 22 and port 2200 to listen to ssh.
Also i enabled the server firewall with the following status.

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
2200/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
2200                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
123                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
2200/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
2200 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
123 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

But now I am experiencing 2 problems.
a.) i am unable to log in as the newly added user

```
ssh grader@publicip
Permission denied (publickey).

$ ssh grader@34.238.159.247 -p 22
Permission denied (publickey).

$ ssh grader@34.238.159.247 -p 2200
Permission denied (publickey).
```

b.) I am unable to find the /etc/sudoers.d/ubuntu file(the user name for lightsail is ubuntu) and i am not able to grant my newly added user the sudo permissions.
Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you are running under the root when you perform your commands. Sudo su.
2. adduser exampleuser
3. usermod -aG sudo exampleuser

This will grant the user the sudo rights, however will not allow you to log in via SSH with that user. Ubuntu is the default and the key generated initially on intsall is ties to this user.

I have not tried the next step yet, however you could generate a new key pair via your mac or whatever machine you are using. Make sure the local username matches your remote user and copy the key onto the Ubuntu in lightsail.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-16-04